# excel formula using conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Im using dates on my spreadsheet and I want to show a date to be highlighted if its greater than another cell by 18 months, If its less than another cell by 18 months, if it is between 9-12 months of another cell I would like to have it highlighted.

So for example
cell A1= 2/1/2019
cell B1= 7/1/2020

I want cell B1 to be green if it is 18 months or greater than cell A1

I want B1 to be blue if it is between 15-17 months less than cell A1

I want B1 to be yellow if it is 14 months or less than cell A1

Hoping you can help please.

Answer (score 1):

The following snip shows the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager dialogue with the formats in the correct order.  The formulas in column D are in the same order.
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Mark! I am running into a challenge where the format is only applying to the first row. The remaining rows arent changing colors correctly. I have the formula correct and applied to the highlighted cells. any tips?

Comment: Referencing a cell coordinate with `$` locks that reference in place. If you reference `$A$1` then copy and paste that cell randomly, they will always refer to `A1`. If you reference `A$1` then the row number will float relative to where you paste but the column will stay `1`. `$A1` will lock the column but the row will float relative to the destination cell. And if you reference `A1` then both the row and column will float relative to where you paste.

Comment: So based on the scenario I should be using $A$1 so the formula can be applied the same to the row and same column?

Comment: I used =$A1<=Edate($B$1,-18). One of the rows in the same column didnt change color. I have the conditional format listed to apply to those cells and it only applied to two out of 3.

Comment: If you have rows of date pairs and want the second column date to change its colour relative to its matching date, you will want do remove ALL `$` symbols as that locks either the row or column it's looking at in place. B1's conditional formatting would reference `A1`. If you have one original date and a column of dates you want to compare to that singular date you reference that cell's row and column with $ symbols `$A$1` So it doesn't matter where the second date is, its always compared to the date in `A1`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `EDATE(start-date,months-to-add)`

Conditional Rules applied to B1:

1. Cell value >= EDATE(A1,18)
2. Cell value between EDATE(A1,15) and EDATE(A1,17)
3. Cell value <= EDate(A1,14)

Comment: Thank you! Some of the formulas arent working to highlight.  Number 2. Am I putting =B1 <=Edate(A1,15) and Edate(A1,17). This isnt working in excel  nor when I change the dates the colors dont change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mark & SHawarden yall both are awesome! I so appreciate your help. Thank you so very much!